# Facebooker gem does not seem to work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebooker

I tried to get the facebooker gem to work with jQuery, but it does not even render the facebook connect buttons, once I load jquery.js instead of prototype.js and use 
init_fb_connect “XFBML”, :js => “jquery”

I tried it with the example
http://www.madebymany.co.uk/tutorial-for-restful_authentication-on-rails-with-facebook-connect-in-15-minutes-00523

Anybody has a clue if it does require prototype or am I doing something really wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call the init_fb_connect helper method in your view, you can specify jQuery or Prototype via the :js option, like so...

```
<%= init_fb_connect "XFBML", :js => :jquery %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the problem was that I loaded facebooker.js, which does not work with jQuery, but it is also not required for the facebook connect functionality!

Comment: Whoo, saved me a bunch of not-helpful typing I was about to start :-) Good catch!